# Vacuum Energy in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

I am studying from Zee's 'QFT in a Nutshell' and very elegantly he reduces all of QFT into one single equation (Pages 43, 88).

[image]

Where the **phi** and **m** are for the free field, **phi-4** is the anharmonicity and **J** is for the vacuum (Page 20-21). The integral looks really cumbersome, and there is no direct solution to it (viz. recall Navier-Stokes Equation!), rather the above equation is amenable to specific conditions, approximations and particular mathematical tricks and techniques.

I am not an expert on QFT, but I have a substantial background in QM. What really bugs me is that the vacuum energy or the zero-point energy (viz. Casimir effect) tends to be an outcome of Schrödinger's equation solved for harmonic oscillator and we do not tend to assume it prior to finding it out - it is one of the most profound outcomes of QM through the the laborious playing with the Gauss-Hermite polynomials. Also, vacuum/zero-point energy may not exist in all QM/QFT systems (viz. free particle, particle in a box etc.). Thus my question - Why do we (and Zee) insert **J** into the above equation as a pre-theory (and not as a conclusion)?

Comment: Why do you think that $J$ has something to do with the vacuum energy? It's just a probe used to compute correlators.

Comment: mike-stone Please read Pages 20-21 of Zee

Comment: I do not have Zee.   Using $J$ to define the generting function and  the effective potential is standard stuff and has nothing directly to with the vacuum energy from the zero point fluctuations That is an undefined additive constant.

Comment: I think you are just misreading Zee. On page 20, he describes the vacuum in terms of the $J=0$ path integral, and then in the next sections he considers adding $J$ as a way to consider excited configurations. E.g. on page 28 he calculates the energy (w.r.t. the vacuum) of two point sources. Nowhere does he imply "J is for the vacuum."

Comment: Okay guys! got it ... Peskin page 289-292 has details of J. Back to Zee, J is source function. As Zee writes, "J(x) can vanish everywhere in spacetime except in some localized regions."